# Обновление текста в startForeground без назойливости

Tags: android

Есть сервис, после запросов по сети он обновляет информацию и по сути в UI должен показывать пользователю одну строку. Очевидное тривиальное решение - `startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)` - всё замечательно работает, но... При каждом ее вызове notification всплывает и это реально бесит. Даже раз в 1-2 минуты. Пользователь просто хотел бы смотреть на это оповещение, когда он хочет. Как реализовать правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Сам спросил, сам ответил...

Для API >= 26 `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` заменить на `IMPORTANCE_NONE`

```
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new 
  NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, 
    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
```

Для тех, что ранее у notification

```
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_LOW)
```